# Why I can not trigger click event inside a click event of the same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple register form -with button Register- in my project. In click of the button, I want to check correctness of credentials and submit the form only when all credentials are okay. You can see my code architecture for this purpose below:

My registration form:

```
<div class="signupContainer">

      <form method="post" action="dbRegistration.php">

          <h1>Sign Up</h1>
          <p>Please fill in the form below to create an account.</p>
          <hr>
          <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
          <input type="text" id="reg_mail" placeholder="Please enter a valid E-mail address" name="email" required>
          <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
          <input type="password" id="reg_pass" placeholder="Please enter a valid password" name="psw" required>
          <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
          <input type="password" id="reg_pass_rw" placeholder="Please repeat the password" name="psw-repeat" required>
          <hr>
          <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>

      </form>

    </div>
```

My JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.registerbtn').prop('type','button');

    $(".registerbtn").click(function(){

      switch(checkCredentials())
      {
        case "notValidEmail":
          alert("Please type a valid E-mail address!");
          break;

        case "notValidPassword":
          alert("Please type a valid password! (at least one lower-case alphabetic character, and at least one other character that is either alphabetical uppercase or numeric)");
          break;

        case "notMatchedPasswords":
          alert("Passwords do not match!");
          break;

        case true:
          $('.registerbtn').prop('type', 'submit');
          $('.registerbtn').trigger('click');
          break;
      }
    });
   });

 </script>
```

```
function checkCredentials()
{
  var check = $('#reg_mail').val();

  if(!check.includes('@'))
    return "notValidEmail";

  check = $('#reg_pass').val();

  if(check.search(/[a-z]/) < 0)
    return "notValidPassword";
  else if(check.search(/[0-9A-Z]/) < 0)
    return "notValidPassword";

  var check_2 = $('#reg_pass_rw').val();

  if(check === check_2)
    return true;
  else
    return "notMatchedPasswords";
}
```

When document is loaded, first I change the button type from "submit" to "button". Then in every click on register button, "checkCredentials()" function returns true if there is no mistake in form and when it returns true, function changes the button property back to "submit" and triggers click event. Program works properly with mistaken inputs but nothing happens when all inputs are okay. What is the thing that I am missing? Thank you for your interest!

Comment: First are you sure you are getting to `$('.registerbtn').trigger('click');` ?? Second you could try with `$('.signupContainer form').submit();`

Comment: I've tested your code and it works just fine for me. Please include your `checkCredentials` method

Comment: Could you please change the case of `TRUE` to `true`? Assuming your `checkCredentials` method is returning `true`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I updated the top message with my checkCredentials function. It is weird because I can not even get into the case true. I am missing something.

Comment: In registration button click  function(event) add at first line  event.preventDefault();

Comment: @bbasaran Again, You code works just fine for me. try it here https://jsfiddle.net/pLm0ugk1/

Comment: @MangeshAuti I tried but it did not work.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I tried with chrome, it worked! I do not understand why it is not working properly on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the case of `TRUE` to `true`. Also consider using `submit` instead of changing the button type and triggering `click` event as it will cause recursive calls. I've assumed `checkCredentials` returns `true` as you want to check the click condition

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.registerbtn').prop('type', 'button');

  $(".registerbtn").click(function() {

    switch (checkCredentials()) {
      case "notValidEmail":
        alert("Please type a valid E-mail address!");
        break;

      case "notValidPassword":
        alert("Please type a valid password! (at least one lower-case alphabetic character, and at least one other character that is either alphabetical uppercase or numeric)");
        break;

      case "notMatchedPasswords":
        alert("Passwords do not match!");
        break;

      case true:
        //$('.registerbtn').prop('type', 'submit');
        $("form").submit();
        console.log("click!");
        break;
    }
  });
});

function checkCredentials() {
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="signupContainer">

  <form method="post" action="dbRegistration.php">

    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <p>Please fill in the form below to create an account.</p>
    <hr>
    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="reg_mail" placeholder="Please enter a valid E-mail address" name="email" required>
    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" id="reg_pass" placeholder="Please enter a valid password" name="psw" required>
    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" id="reg_pass_rw" placeholder="Please repeat the password" name="psw-repeat" required>
    <hr>
    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: I changed TRUE to true for both in checkCredentials function and my js function. On the other hand, I tried to use just " $("form").submit(); " instead, but both of these solutions did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your code to use submit instead of the button, then, manage the submit request with preventDefault():

```
  //If you can manage the form
  $("#myform").submit(function(event){
    if(checkCredentials()) { 
       event.preventDefault();  
    }  
  });

  //If you want manage the button
  $("#yourbutton").on('click', function(event){
    if (checkCredentials()) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```